# Annoying message when I start a debug session in the Windows CE 4.1 emulator

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, emulation, visual-studio-2003

I have to maintain an old Compact Framework application written for Windows CE 4.1 in Visual Studio 2003 (sigh!). It's the German localized version of Visual Studio 2003.

Every time i start a debug session in the WinCE emulator, I get this message on the virtual device:

> "Microsoft .NET CF 1.0 DE-String ist
>   bereits installiert.  Möchten Sie
>   erneut installieren?"

which translated into English means:

> "Microsoft .NET CF 1.0 DE-String is
>   already installed.  Do you want to
>   re-install it?"

After clicking "OK" the app runs normally, but it is very annoying havong to click this every time I test the application. Is there a solution for this?

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

You want to turn off deploying the compact framework to the mobile device when deploying. This is an option that you can turn off in your project properties menu on the devices tab that will stop this from happening each time.

Comment: I can't find these option in VS 2003. Could you please tell me where exactly I have to look? There is no "devices tab" in my project properties.